# How to list/show most recent data in a ksql stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have created a ksql stream using

```
CREATE STREAM basic_streams (data VARCHAR) \
 WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='main-topic',VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

I have a producer running, pumping data into the stream. Is it possible to list/show the most recent items sent to the ksql stream?

Thanks

P.S. I tried in ksql server and the results are

```
ksql> list streams;

 Stream Name   | Kafka Topic              | Format
---------------------------------------------------
 BASIC_STREAMS | main-topic | JSON
---------------------------------------------------
ksql> PRINT main-topic;
Could not find topic 'MAIN-TOPIC', KSQL uses uppercase.
To print a case-sensitive topic apply quotations, for example: print 'topic';
```

and when i tried

```
ksql> print 'main-topic';
```

it hangs there forever

Comment: Did you try `PRINT main-topic`?

Comment: was this in kafka or ksql server?

Comment: Well, `PRINT` is not a Kafka term, so KSQL https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/261#issuecomment-325859822 And it hangs waiting for data from the latest offset

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

- `PRINT 'main-topic' FROM BEGINNING;` to see all rows in topic.
- `PRINT 'main-topic'; to see all rows added to the topic
- `PRINT main-topic;` in more recent versions of ksqlDB as the topic name is case-sensitive
- Or `SELECT * FROM basic_streams;` to achieve the same in a more SQL way.